# Need help configuring cookies in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, cookies, puppeteer

is there a way to use cookies from my Chrome, in order to use it in puppeteer chromium? Im trying to scrape a website with a login form and a captha, was hoping to bypass that by useing cookies, but it is hard to decypher info about it here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can call `await page.setCookie(cookie1, cookie2)`
you can spread an array inside `await page.setCookie(...array)`

this is an example of cookie

```
{
  domain: // website domain,
  expirationDate: 1597288045,
  hostOnly: false,
  httpOnly: false,
  name: 'name',
  path: '/',
  sameSite: 'no_restriction',
  secure: false,
  session: false,
  storeId: '0',
  value: '100',
  id: 1,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This a fairly simple example of what I think you are trying to achieve.

```
(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
 const page = await browser.newPage()
 await page.setCookie(cookie)
 await page.goto('url')
})()
```

And cookie can be anything like this

```
{
    'name':'Name of the cookie',
    'value':'Value of the cookie'
}
```

You should try to avoid using SO as a reference guide. Go to the official documentation of what you are using.

[Puppeteer set cookie documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.1.0&show=api-pagesetcookiecookies)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's just that for a pleb noob like me documentation is too complex. Do i just create a file inside my project folder and fill in file in json with login, pass, etc?

Comment: Nope, you will have to capture the cookie from a browser where you are logged in the page and use it like so. The cookies does not contain your username/password, they usually contain a token + refresh token or any other type of authentication.  I recommend using a chrome extension like EditThisCookie or so.  Depending on the page you want to scrape, this method wont work because of cookie signature.  Anyway I recommend you to keep up the hard work and stick to reading more documentation abou this. It may be confusing first, but you'll grow faster.

Comment: @SebastianCiocarlan - Perfect. Yeah, I didn't know if it was voting or seeing it marked duplicate or just figuring it out yourself. :-) Happy coding!